# How To Find the Script Responsible for Certain Action

Tags: javascript

I want to imitate the left-right scrolling functionality of this webpage, with left and right arrows that pan the row of divs accordingly:

http://www.stuartmcmillen.com/comics_en/rat-park/

I've been trying to find the bit of javascript that makes this effect happen in the firefox debugger, but I'm a total front end noob, I feel like I've looked through every script on the page but I can't find what's causing the animation when the left and right arrows are clicked. I tried using the firefox profiler but the output is unintelligible. How do I find the javascript responsible for this left right scrolling animation? Or is it even javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time you can inspect the element and look for the id attribute or a descriptive class name, then search the script for those values, in your case the code for the arrow buttons starts at line 1770 of the page source, I found it looking for the id `#left_arrow`

Comment: oh, brilliant. is there some tool that can do this for you or do you always have to just grep it out yourself?

Comment: @qwwqwwq I don't know of any tool but it's pretty simple to do, I used Chrome Inspector to get the id value, then Ctrl+U to get the page source, then Ctrl+F to get the search box, typed in and voila!, if I wouldn't have found anything in the page source then I would've looked for referenced js files and done the same there

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Script:

```
var cur = 1;
var 

max = $(".collectionsCnt2").children("li").length;

$(".button-right").click(function () {

    if (cur >= max) return;
    cur =  cur + (500/100 < max ? 500/100 : max);

    $(".collectionsCnt2").animate({
        marginLeft: "-=500px",
    }, 1000);

});

$(".button-left").click(function () {
    if (cur <= 1) return;
    cur =  cur - (500/100 < max ? 500/100 : max);
    $(".collectionsCnt2").animate({
        marginLeft: "+=500px",
    }, 1000);

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/45Exw/5/)

May be this can provide you some help.

Comment: awesome, that fiddle was exactly what i was hoping someone would post

Comment: @qwwqwwq actually your question was about finding code in a page, for which I provided an answer, if you wanted some code then you should have asked for an implementation for that behavior

Comment: yeah you're correct, I was just excited because someone went and gave me a fish instead of teaching me how to fish.. I'll accept you

Answer (score 0):

There is so much there, its tough to find the result quickly...

I think you are talking about the slide show left / right arrows.. check out the samples at http://red-canoe.com.  Sometimes its easier to start simple.  The JS comes from:

```
    Supersized - Fullscreen Slideshow jQuery Plugin
    Version : Core 3.2.1
    Site    : www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized
    Author  : Sam Dunn
```